# R paste values dynamically with seperator

Tags: r, paste, string-concatenation, concatenation

I want to paste a number of arguments which vary according to a parameter, with a comma separator "," between them.
For instance:

```
pred.size <- 2
paste(c(1:pred.size), sep=",")
```

results in:

```
##"1" "2"
```

while the result I want is:

```
##"1","2"
```

Comment: Do you mean the result you want is `"1,2"` as a single string?

Comment: Try `paste(c(1:pred.size), collapse=",")` or `paste(seq_len(pred.size), collapse=",")`

Comment: If you really want the quotes in the string, try:  `paste(1:pred.size,collapse="\",\"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to paste together the elements of a vector like `1:2` to get a comma separated string. To do this you use the `collapse` argument of paste, since you are passing it only a single argument.

```
paste(1:3, collapse = ",")
[1] "1,2,3"
```

On the other hand if you passed multiple terms you would use `sep`:

```
paste(1, 2, 3, sep = ",")
[1] "1,2,3"
```

`sep` separates the arguments, `collapse` separates the components of vector arguments. For example:

```
paste(1:4, 5:8, collapse=",", sep="|")
[1] "1|5,2|6,3|7,4|8"
```

Type `?paste` at the R prompt for more information.

So you want

```
paste(1:pred.size, collapse=",")
```

Your `c` is not necessary because `1:pred_size` is already a vector.